# Does VMware 11 provide real GPU up to 2GB memory allocation or just facilitates allocating the same VRAM that comes from the allocated RAM?

Tags: vmware-workstation, hypervisor

Their advertisement is pretty confusing: *Graphics-intensive applications can now be given an additional boost by allocating up to 2 GB of video memory per virtual machine.*

I just want to confirm if this is VRAM and not some sort of rather revolutionary pass-through without the head-aches of Hyper-Visor (ESXi) and hardware compatibility issues.

Thanks